# Prism RequestNavigate

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

In my mainwindow i have a tab control, i need to notify different modules that different tabs has been activated or closed.  The tabcontrols SelectedItem is bound to ActiveView in my viewmodel

```
<TabControl Padding="0"  SelectedItem="{Binding ActiveView}"
                    x:Name="MainViewTab" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.MainRegion}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource TabHeaderStyle}" 
                    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="MainViewDeatilTab"        
 />
```

In the region Mainregion i load different views

```
 UriQuery parameters = new UriQuery();
            parameters.Add("OBJECTID", item.ObjectId.ToString());
            regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainRegion,
                                            new Uri("AIT.Modules.SiteEditor.Views.SiteEditor" + parameters.ToString(), UriKind.Relative),
                                            NavigationCompleted);
```

The selecteditem is bound to property ActiveView and in  the property i need to raise an event that contains OBJECTID as a paramenter.

My problem is that the tabcontrols SelectedItem fires before the view has a chance to load the OBJECTID parameter, which i load in Prism OnNavigatedTo . Anyone has an example on how you manage tabcontrols open and close events so other modules can be notified about current views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not detesting code-behind within your mainwindow, you may subscribe the public `Navigated` event of the region's navigation service one can access via the `NavigationService`-property of `IRegion`. The corresponding event handler gets the `NavigationContext` of the navigation request and thus the URI.
As an compromise you could just delegate the event handling from your mainwindow-code-behind to your viewmodel.
This is at least one approach I once used.

To avoid the code-behind, you could write a attached property for the RegionManager that does the connection between the event and your viewmodel for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks i solved it in another way , but yours seems better. Was not aware of the NavigatonService